# Understanding optional chaining and optionally unwrapped Optionals

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, option-type

**Consider the following code block**

```
// self is a UIViewController
let f = self.view.window?.rootViewController?.view.frame
```

Here f is an Optional wrapping CGRect.
As far as I can understand,

- *view* is implicitly unwrapped property.(i.e. UIView!).
- We access the *window* property of it with optionally unwrapping the optional window property of view. If it has value then access its *rootViewController* property else do nothing.
- Similarly we optionally unwrap *rootViewController* and access its *view* property.
- Finally we get *frame* of view.

Since any of the *window* or *rootViewController* can be nil, frame is an Optional.

**Am I understanding it correctly.**
**Also why the *view* property of *UIViewcontroller* is optional?**

Comment: `view` of this: `rootViewController?.view`?

Comment: @Mr.Bista view is not optional. it is implicitly unwrapped optional. It can't be nil therefore you can't optional chain it.

Comment: Ya, that's why i was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

> “Specifically, the result of an optional chaining call is of the same type as the expected return value, but wrapped in an optional. A property that normally returns an Int will return an Int? when accessed through optional chaining.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).” iBooks.

`UIViewController` implements lazy loading of its view.  The [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) method is responsible for either loading the view hierarchy (from a NIB or Storyboard scene) or creating it through code.  As a result, `view` will be `nil` between initialisation and when the `view` propery is first referenced.

Answer (score 0):

> view is implicitly unwrapped property.(i.e. UIView!).

Correct.

> We access the window property of it with optionally unwrapping the optional window property of view. If it has value then access its rootViewController property else do nothing.

The first part is correct, but the second part is a little wrong. If `window` does not have a value i.e. `nil`, the code does *not* do nothing. The whole expression evaluates to `nil`. In this case, `nil` will be assigned to `f`.

> Similarly we optionally unwrap rootViewController and access its view property.
>
> Finally we get frame of view.

That's right.

> Since any of the window or rootViewController can be nil, frame is an Optional.

Technically, no. `frame` is still a non-optional type. It only *seems* like an optional because all those unwrapping you did. `f` *is* an optional though.

> Also why the view property of UIViewcontroller is optional?

The purpose of `UIViewController` is to control and manage a `UIView`. When `UIViewController` is initialized, there isn't neccessarily a view for it to manage! The view is loaded just before `viewDidLoad` is called (in the `loadView` method). That's why you do all the adding subviews code in `viewDidLoad` instead of in the initializer.